# Проверка переменной на целое число

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
$int = is_int($_GET['section']);
if ($int == false) {$_GET['section'] = 1;}
echo $_GET['section'];
```

В переменную `$int` я заношу результат проверки переменной `$_GET['section']` на целое число. Результатом может быть `true`, если переменная целое число и `false`, если нет. Далее идёт условие, согласно которому, если результат проверки `false`, то переменная `$_GET['section']` должна стать равной 1. Далее выводится само значение переменной.

На практике:

Действительно, если переменная содержит не целое число (например, *`http://localhost/section.php?section=%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B`*), то переменная становится равной 1. Но, если переменная содержит целое число (например, `http://localhost/section.php?section=5`), переменная всё равно равна 1 вместо 5. Почему?

Answer (score 4):

Все переменные которые приходят приходят в РНР по протоколу НТТР, трактуются как строки. поэтому применять к ним функцию is_int бесполезно.

Если надо выяснить, является ли строка целым числом, следует использовать функцию `ctype_digit()`.

Если нам не надо проверять, а достаточно *привести* к целочисленному типу (то есть, допустимым значением является "25 лошадок", от которых должно остаться число 25), то можно использовать функции приведения типов

Answer (score 0):

Вроде все правильно у Вас. Можем попробовать по-другому

```
if(isset($_GET['section']))
   $int = (int)$_GET['section'];
else
   exit("Переменная не переданная");
if($int == 0)
   $int = 1;
echo $int;
```

Comment: Оказывается GET не разбирается в типах string это или intval. Надо использовать is_numeric().